# Why gulp-sourcemaps output breaks with gulp-strip-css-comments?

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-sourcemaps

I would like to remove all the comments from the CSS code but I have noticed that when I added [gulp-strip-css-comments](https://github.com/sindresorhus/strip-css-comments) to my gulp task the sourcemap no longer works, even when I'm making sure that *gulp-strip-css-comments* keeps the comment that points to the source map `/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */` by using the regular expression option.

Below I have added my code and output before and after using *gulp-strip-css-comments*:

**Before gulp-strip-css-comments**

```
gulp.task('sass:dev', function () {
  gulp.src('./sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(
      sass({
        includePaths: [
          './node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/'
        ]
      })
      .on('error', sass.logError)
    )
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 version', 'ie 11']
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```

[image]

**After gulp-strip-css-comments**

```
gulp.task('sass:dev', function () {
  gulp.src('./sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(
      sass({
        includePaths: [
          './node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/'
        ]
      })
      .on('error', sass.logError)
    )
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 version', 'ie 11']
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(stripCssComments({preserve: /^# sourceMappingURL=/}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```

[image]

Comment: [Not supported.](https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps/wiki/Plugins-with-gulp-sourcemaps-support)

Answer (score 0):

Put stripCssComments code before sourcemaps .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))

```js
gulp.task('sass:dev', function () {
  gulp.src('./sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(
      sass({
        includePaths: [
          './node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/'
        ]
      })
      .on('error', sass.logError)
    )
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 version', 'ie 11']
    }))
    .pipe(stripCssComments({preserve: /^# sourceMappingURL=/}))  
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```